# How to get tipsy to work on all elemets that have title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get tipsy to show on all links or other elements that have title?

For example...

```
<a href="/home" title="Go back to the index page">Home</a>
```

So I see "Go back to the index page" when hover, but with no id for, I want to it basically be a tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*[title]').tipsy();
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('[title!=""]').tipsy();
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct you are looking for something like:

**EDITED:**

```
// Select all elements in body     
$('body *').each(function() {
    // check if element has title
    if ($(this).attr("title")) {
        // Start tipsy
        $(this).tipsy();
    } else {
       // Do something or exlude *else* if u dont need
    }
});
```